# Laravel Explicit route model binding issue in RouteServiceProvider

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, routes

I am using **Explicit route model binding** for **Slider module** in my Laravel (**5.6** version )application. Now I am facing an issue when i try to join sliders table with file_uploads table.

**RouteServiceProvider**

```
$this->bind('slider', function ($value) {
    $slider = new Slider;

    return Slider::withTrashed()
                  ->leftjoin('file_uploads','file_uploads.file_code', '=', 'sliders.file_code')
                  ->where('sliders.id', $value)->first();
});
```

this is the code am using. 
Both **sliders** and **file_uploads** table have **ID** column. And in slider edit page am getting ID from `file_uploads` table. My intended ID will be from `sliders` table.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: do you need `sliders.id` or rather just use ('id', '=', $value)?

Comment: Yes. Sliders.id is needed. Because both tables have id column..

Comment: How about using using select I think using select() e.g -`->where('sliders.id', $value)->select('*', 'sliders.id as sliders_id')` then retrieve it from wherever you need it or pass it in as `->first(['*', 'sliders.id as sliders_id'])` . Eloquent relationship would have saved this headache though.

Comment: wow. Now it is working. Thank you. Please paste it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had used [Eloquent Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) it could have saved you having the one `id` property from a table override another due to `joins`.

But for the sake of using [Joins](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins) then you can retrieve the needed id as another property using `select()` (see [Selects](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#selects)) or passing the array parameters to the `first()` method so your code becomes:

```
return Slider::withTrashed()
              ->leftjoin('file_uploads','file_uploads.file_code', '=', 'sliders.file_code')
              ->where('sliders.id', $value)
              ->first(['*', 'sliders.id as sliders_id']);
```

Or:

```
return Slider::withTrashed()
              ->leftjoin('file_uploads','file_uploads.file_code', '=', 'sliders.file_code')
              ->where('sliders.id', $value)
              ->select('*', 'sliders.id as sliders_id')
              ->first();
```

Either way the select statement is passed as query and the `id` value is returned as `sliders_id` and you can use that where you needed the `id` instead.